# ASP, javascript panel (Show/Hide) wont display the ASP text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This problem occurs when i click the panel to show a login box if no session is registered.

Here is the Panel:

```
<div id='demo-header'>
        <a id='login-link' href='#login'>



           <%  If Session("user") Is Nothing Then

                Response.Write("Login Panel")
            Else

                Response.Write("Links")

            End If
            %>



            </a>
        <div id='login-panel'>

 <%  If Session("user") Is Nothing Then

    Response.Write("<p><font color='White'>Username: <br />")
    Response.Write("<asp:TextBox ID='txtUsername' runat='server'>qwerty</asp:TextBox> </font><br />")
    Response.Write("<p><font color='White'>Password:  <br />")
    Response.Write("<asp:TextBox ID='txtPassword' runat='server'></asp:TextBox> <br />")
    Response.Write("<asp:Button ID='Button1' runat='server' Text='Login'>")
    Response.Write("<font color='White'><small>Press ESC to close</small></font> <a title='Register' href='registerUser.aspx'> Register</a>")

            Else

                Response.Write("<table>")
                Response.Write("<tr>")

                Response.Write("<td><a id='login-link' href='#login' title='Login'> <a href='account.aspx'>Account</a></br><a href='logout.aspx'>Logout</a></td>")
                Response.Write("</table>")
                Response.Write("</tr>")

            End If%>  </div>     <!-- /login-panel -->


</div>
```

i am unable to show the ASP text boxes, but text is displayed with gaps where my text boxes should be.

I Would like to know if the resposne.write lines are correct

Comment: is this incorrectly tagged as asp.net?

Comment: no why, this is an ASP problem

Comment: asp.net and asp are different beasts. You should not try to output an asp:Button or an asp:Textbox as these are server controls in asp.net. the browser doesn't recognize them.